# C++ Long Division

Tags: c++

Whilst working on a personal project of mine, I came across a need to divide two very large arbitrary numbers (each number having roughly 100 digits). 
So i wrote out the very basic code for division (i.e., answer = a/b, where a and b are imputed by the user)and quickly discovered that it only has a precision of 16 digits! It may be obvious at this point that Im not a coder!

So i searched the internet and found a code that, as far as i can tell, uses the traditional method of long division by making a string(but too be honest im not sure as im quite confused by it). But upon running the code it gives out some incorrect answers and wont work at all if a>b.
Im not even sure if there's a better way to solve this problem than the method in the code below!? Maybe there's a simpler code??

So basically i need help to write a code, in C++, to divide two very large numbers. 
Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;  //avoids having to use std:: with cout/cin



int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    string dividend, divisor, difference, a, b, s, tempstring = ""; // a and b used to store dividend and divisor.
    int quotient, inta, intb, diff, tempint = 0;
    char d;

    quotient = 0;

    cout << "Enter the dividend?  ";      //larger number (on top)
    cin  >> a;
    cout << "Enter the divisor?  ";           //smaller number (on bottom)
    cin  >> b;

    //making the strings the same length by adding 0's to the beggining of string.
    while (a.length() < b.length())  a = '0'+a;          // a has less digits than b add 0's
     while (b.length() < a.length())  b = '0'+b;          // b has less digits than a add 0's

    inta = a[0]-'0';                        // getting first digit in both strings
    intb = b[0]-'0';

    //if a<b print remainder out (a) and return 0
    if (inta < intb)
    {
        cout << "Quotient: 0 " << endl << "Remainder: " << a << endl;
    }


    else
    {
        a = '0'+a;
        b = '0'+b;
        diff = intb;
        //s = b;
       // while ( s >= b )

        do
        {
            for (int i = a.length()-1; i>=0; i--)            // do subtraction until end of string
            {
            inta = a[i]-'0';                    // converting ascii to int, used for munipulation
            intb = b[i]-'0';   
            if (inta < intb)                 // borrow if needed
            {
              a[i-1]--;                         //borrow from next digit
              a[i] += 10;
            }
            diff = a[i] - b[i];
          char d = diff+'0';
           s = d + s;                           //this + is appending two strings, not performing addition.

            }
         quotient++;
         a = s;
        // strcpy (a, s);
        } 

        while (s >= b); // fails after dividing 3 x's

    cout << "s string: " << s << endl;
     cout << "a string: " << a << endl;
     cout << "Quotient:  " << quotient << endl;
     //cout << "Remainder: " << s << endl;

    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
    cin.get(); // allows the user to enter variable without instantly ending the program
    cin.get(); // allows the user to enter variable without instantly ending the program
```

}

Comment: There are plenty of bignum libraries out there with C++ bindings. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries) lists GMP (LGPL), Boost (possibly LGPL if you link it against GMP), TTMath (BSD), and MAPM.

Answer (score 2):

There are much better methods than that. This subtractive method is arbitrarily slow for large dividends and small divisors. The canonical method is given as Algorithm D in Knuth, D.E., *The Art of Computer Programming,* volume 2, but I'm sure you will find it online. I'd be astonished if it wasn't in Wikipedia somewhere.

Comment: The Hacker's Delight site has Algorithm D for 16-bit 'digits' here: http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/divmnu.c.txt

Comment: ^^ I'd much rather subtract than looking at all that hex code in main.. as well as the dirty look of those algorithms..

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Surely you jest. You'd rather wait for an `O(N**3)` algorithm? And there is no hex code in Algorithm D, and nothing dirty about it either. This particular implementation uses a `goto` where it should use a `while` loop but apart from that it seems OK.