# Function to divide two numbers without using division (/) operator and returning quotient in decimal point format

Tags: c++, c

This problem may appear trivial but the catch is the quotient should be in decimal point format as shown in below example:

1. 15/2 = 7.5
2. 10/3 = 3.33

Following is the code which I know will work if I need to return the floor value ie 15/2 = 7. Here it is the sample code (error checks and sign checks have been removed):

```
float divide(float dividend, float divisor) 
{
    float quotient = 0;
    while (dividend >= divisor) 
    {
        dividend = dividend - divisor;
        ++quotient;
    }
    return quotient;
}
```

Please suggest the required modification to return quotient in decimal point. Following are few more constraints:
Cant use: Any inbuilt function, *, /, %
Allowed to use: +, -, bitwise operators, loops, recursion.

Comment: How about `std::modf(a / b, 0)`?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22889596/1460794) is some information on how to do it with the bits directly (links to other page)